# Want data added to the Query via Left Outer Joint to NOT repeat

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, right-join

I have a database structure (ER diagram below) that has three level of hierarchical data and the fourth level of optional data.
[image]

**If I write a query to get de-normalized data of three levels - level 1 to level 3 with sample data across three tables shown as below:**

[image]

**When queried, this layout of the data is very straight forward and as expected as below:**

[image]

Upon running the below query, I get the following output (And I have tried various combinations by clubbing the set of L1 to L4 and moving one L4 out as a another query and then joining the set L1 - L4 etc.) - again this is on the expected lines.

```
SELECT        [Group].GroupId, [Group].GroupName, Category.CategoryId, Category.CategoryName, RLI.RLIId, RLI.RLIText, Comment.CommentId, Comment.CommentText, ManagementResponse.ManagementResponseId, 
                         ManagementResponse.ManagementResponseTest
FROM            Category INNER JOIN
                         [Group] ON Category.GroupId = [Group].GroupId INNER JOIN
                         RLI ON Category.CategoryId = RLI.CategoryId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         ManagementResponse ON RLI.RLIId = ManagementResponse.RLIId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Comment ON RLI.RLIId = Comment.RLIId
```

[image]

However, I need data in the following format - and this is what I am unable to figure out how to get (**I don't want the level 4 data to repeat as I add additional level 4 data via left outer joins**):
[image]

Comment: did u try inner joins instead of a left join ?

Comment: Not sure how inner join would be the solution since the data at level 4 is optional. Inner join would cause the upper level data to be lost.

Comment: Is the equality of `CommentId` and `ManagementResponseId` in the desired output intentional or coincidental?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you the final output:
[image]

```
WITH CommentAndResponse AS (

SELECT Comment.CommentId,
         Comment.CommentText, 
         ManagementResponse.ManagementResponseId, 
         ManagementResponse.ManagementResponseTest,
    COALESCE(Comment.RLIId, ManagementResponse.RLIId) AS RLIId
 FROM (
    (SELECT Comment.CommentId, 
            Comment.CommentText,
            Comment.RLIId,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Comment.RLIId ORDER BY Comment.CommentId) AS CommentRowNumber
    FROM Comment) AS Comment
    FULL JOIN
    (SELECT  ManagementResponse.ManagementResponseId, 
            ManagementResponse.ManagementResponseTest,
            ManagementResponse.RLIId,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ManagementResponse.RLIId ORDER BY ManagementResponse.ManagementResponseId) AS ManagementResponseRowNumber   
    FROM ManagementResponse) AS ManagementResponse
    ON Comment.CommentRowNumber = ManagementResponse.ManagementResponseRowNumber AND Comment.RLIId = ManagementResponse.RLIId ) 
    )

SELECT          [Group].GroupId, [Group].GroupName, Category.CategoryId, Category.CategoryName, RLI.RLIId, RLI.RLIText, CommentAndResponse.CommentId, CommentAndResponse.CommentText, CommentAndResponse.ManagementResponseId, CommentAndResponse.ManagementResponseTest
FROM            [Category]
INNER JOIN      [Group] ON Category.GroupId = [Group].GroupId 
INNER JOIN      [RLI] ON Category.CategoryId = RLI.CategoryId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [CommentAndResponse] ON RLI.RLIId = CommentAndResponse.RLIId
```

Comment: that was perfect. Good one!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify that `Comment.CommentId` is equal to `ManagementResponse.ManagementResponseId` or either is null. That can be part of a `JOIN` or a separate `WHERE`

```
SELECT          [Group].GroupId, [Group].GroupName, Category.CategoryId, Category.CategoryName, RLI.RLIId, RLI.RLIText, Comment.CommentId, Comment.CommentText, ManagementResponse.ManagementResponseId, 
                         ManagementResponse.ManagementResponseTest
FROM            [Category]
INNER JOIN      [Group] ON Category.GroupId = [Group].GroupId 
INNER JOIN      [RLI] ON Category.CategoryId = RLI.CategoryId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [ManagementResponse] ON RLI.RLIId = ManagementResponse.RLIId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Comment] ON RLI.RLIId = Comment.RLIId
WHERE           ManagementResponse.ManagementResponseId = Comment.CommentId OR ManagementResponse.ManagementResponseId IS NULL OR Comment.CommentId IS NULL
```

This assumes that those IDs begin equal is the relationship you want to model. The example data seems to show this, but it could be a coincidence of how you assembled the example. Alternatively, if there is no relationship between `Comment` and `ManagementResponse` besides `RLIId`, something like

```
WITH CommentAndResponse AS (
    SELECT Comment.CommentId, Comment.CommentText, ManagementResponse.ManagementResponseId, ManagementResponse.ManagementResponseTest,
        COALESCE(Comment.RLIId, ManagementResponse.RLIId) AS RLIId,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Comment.CommentId, ManagementResponse.ManagementResponseId, PARTITION BY Comment.RLIId, ManagementResponse.RLIId) AS rn
    FROM Comment
    FULL JOIN ManagementResponse ON Comment.RLIId = ManagementResponse.RLIId)
SELECT          [Group].GroupId, [Group].GroupName, Category.CategoryId, Category.CategoryName, RLI.RLIId, RLI.RLIText, CommentAndResponse.CommentId, CommentAndResponse.CommentText, CommentAndResponse.ManagementResponseId, CommentAndResponse.ManagementResponseTest
FROM            [Category]
INNER JOIN      [Group] ON Category.GroupId = [Group].GroupId 
INNER JOIN      [RLI] ON Category.CategoryId = RLI.CategoryId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [CommentAndResponse] ON RLI.RLIId = CommentAndResponse.RLIId AND CommentAndResponse.rn = 1
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. One of my team members built upon your solution (which has a syntax issue) and got a working one. See the working solution marked as the answer. Your inputs helped us get there.